# jquery in wordpress not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i added jquery into my wordpress themes/themename/js file and tried to use it, but it doesn't work. It should make my header title red color, but it doesn't.  What am i doing wrong?

I also get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
function twentyfourteen_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'extra js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfourteen_child_scripts' );


 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js');
```

**EXTRA.JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}


jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

   jQuery('.head-title').css('color','red');

});
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php

get_header();

?>

<div class="container">

<div class="secondary-column">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar1');// sinu widgets sidebar ?> 
</div>

<div class="post-content">

<?php

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    get_template_part('content', get_post_format());  // dynamically include the post format - get_post_format() - lubab sul sinu enda nullist üles ehitatud posti lisada. Näide: content-aside.php  

    endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;

?>

    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
            echo paginate_links();
        ?>
    </div>

<?php

get_footer();

?>
```

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>



    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>


        <!-- site-header -->
        <header class="site-header">

            <div class="header-container">
                <nav class="site-nav">

                    <h1 class ="head-title">My website</h1>

                        <!-- hd-search -->
                    <div class="hd-search">
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                    </div><!-- /hd-search -->

                    <?php

                    $args = array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary'
                    );

                    ?>

                    <?php wp_nav_menu(  $args ); ?> 

                    <?php



                    $args2 = array(
                        'child_of' => get_top_ancestor_id(),
                        'title_li' => ''
                    );

                    ?>

                    <div class="children-links">

                        <?php wp_list_pages($args2); ?>

                    </div>


                </nav>


            </div>

        </header><!-- /site-header -->
```

Comment: Just use `$('.head-title').css('color','red');` without any of the function definition.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Try jQuery('.head-title').css('color','red');

Comment: You haven't shown us the HTML - maybe you don't have an element with `head-title` class?

Comment: Alright, i added index.php and header.php

Comment: Ok, i solved the problem somehow

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script loaded after jquery script.
You can use dependency injection when you call your script

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'extra_js', '//path to your script..', [ 'jquery' ] );
```

Notice this part ['jquery'] - this is where you can set array of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress do not need to include jQuery. If You for some reasons need to include other version of jQuery, You must use wp_deregister_script('jquery');

```
jQuery(document).on("ready page:change", function() {

   jQuery('.head-title').css('color','red');

});
```

hierarchy of added scripts is also important. When You add other version of jQ, first deregister default version, then add new version and then wp_enqueue_script where You make some changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use spaces in WordPress script enqueue handles. Also, in your `functions.php` file the call to jQuery is both redundant and outside the function. All you need to do it load your script with a dependency array that includes `jquery` as follows:

```
function twentyfourteen_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'extra-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra.js', array( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfourteen_child_scripts' );
```